# Accessing a variable from multiple source files in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Example:

stdafx.h:

```
#pragma once
typedef void (__stdcall*FuncType)(int,int);
extern FuncType Func1 = NULL;
```

foo.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    printf("%x\n",&Func1);
    return 0;
}
```

foo2.cpp:

```
void call()
{
    printf("%x\n",&Func1);
}
```

Assume both foo.cpp,foo2.cpp included stdafx.h

Linker errors:

```
1>fooTest.obj : error LNK2005: "void (__stdcall* Func1)(int,int)" (?    Func1@@3P6GXHH@ZA) already defined in stdafx.obj
1>foo2.obj : error LNK2005: "void (__stdcall* Func1)(int,int)" (?Func1@@3P6GXHH@ZA) already defined in stdafx.obj
1>C:\Users\****\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\fooTest\Debug\fooTest.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

using static instead of extern compiles fine, but the source files use their own version of Func1, and this is unacceptable as I need them to share the same variable.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you must *define* variable `Func1`, which is just *declared* in the header file, only in one of your source files, not in two; and you must not declare it there as static, since it then would not be visible to other translation units. And I would not set it to `NULL` in the header file but in the (one) source file where you actually define the variable.

Comment: To clarify a bit, the `= NULL` makes `extern FuncType Func1 = NULL;` a **definition**. Putting that definition in the header means that every source file that `#include`s that header ends up with a definition of `Func1`, and that's what the linker is complaining about. This answer is right that the solution is to **declare** `Func1` in the header (by removing `= NULL`) and **defining** it in exactly one source file.

Comment: In C++17 you will be able to just declare it as `inline FuncType Func1 = NULL;` in the header file. The end result is the same: a global variable, except that the burden of creating a unique definition (and choosing the point of definiton) is handed over to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

remove `= NULL` part from the stdafx.h and put the following line in one of your cpp files (only in one cpp).

`FuncType Func1 = NULL;`

Answer (score -1):

When I get problem such as yours, I find that making it a `static` almost always solves the problem. This also apply to most variables, such as your `int`s,  `float`s... , that you store in another file, eiter `.cpp` or `.h`.

Comment: Making it `static` gives each translation unit its own, independent, separate instance of the variable. Which is absolutely NOT what the OP wants to achieve. The OP wants a *single* variable shared by all translation units.